# What is the output of this program and how?

Tags: c, char, overflow

```
#include <stdio.h> 
 int main() 
{   char i=0;            
    for(;i>=0;i++);     
    printf("%d",i);     
    return 0; 
 }
```

The output of this program is -128. As far as i understood the character variable will overflow and all bits will be 0. And taking two's complement will be again 0. Can somebody explain the process?

**EDIT** : Just to clarify that this is not my program. It is a programming question in a competitive exam.

Comment: You have possible *undefined behavior*. Overflowing a signed integer variable leads to UB. And `char` can be either `signed` or `unsigned`.

Comment: First, you should fix the code. This is tagged C and the code is obviously C except for the include and namespace stuff, this doesn't belong here. (put `#include <stdio.h>` instead)

Comment: If you can compile the code exactly as shown in your question, you're using a C++ compiler. It's a bad idea to compile C code with a C++ compiler.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the code you presented, but please treat it as a curiosity only.  Using a signed 8-bit variable as a loop counter is a very bad idea: it very often leads to subtle bugs which can be very difficult to track down.  The right thing to do with overflow of 8-bit signed numbers is not to understand precisely how it works, but to just not use it.

Comment: @Felix Palmen  this is not my program. It's a question from a competitive exam trying to test my knowledge about such concepts

Comment: Then the author of this question should be beaten with a copy of the current C standard ;) *scnr*

Comment: `char` is an *8-bit* and *2's complement* signed value. Your exam question is testing whether you understand that is the case and what it means.

Comment: @lurker sure, but if you're "pedantic" enough, you have to admit you can't be sure about that, it's just the *most likely* thing. So I'd say this is a very bad question. It should at least be written like "what implementation properties would you assume to explain the following output of this program?" or similar.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I understand the general case is a matter of likelihood and that the behavior cannot be expected to be consistent depending upon platform, etc. Obviously, one wouldn't want to write code like this intentionally. But in this case, the question is specifically *Why is the output -128?* and not *What is the expected output?* and not even *Would you expect the output to be -128?*, which are all different questions.

Comment: @lurker exactly, and I'd say that's a bad question, because although there's one **very very likely** answer, you can't be sure about it.

Comment: Why code `using namespace std;` and then tag  C and not C++?  Looks like there is an underlying assumption that the answer is the same for both.

Answer (score 5):

Your assumption about overflowing isn't correct. Overflowing an *unsigned* type will set all bits to zero, but overflowing a *signed* type is *undefined*, so it could result in any value.

What you get as a result therefore depends on your (compiler) implementation. It could be explained if

- Your implementation has *signed* `char`.
- A `char` has 8 bits.
- Negative numbers are represented in 2's complement.
- Overflow of a signed value will cause *wraparound*. (which is the consequence of a simple implementation using 2's complement, see below)

Given all these assumptions (and remember, **none** of these are specified by C), incrementing `127` as the maximum possible `char` value (represented as `0111 1111`) yields `-128`, the minimum possible value (represented as `1000 0000`).

TL;DR -- your code is undefined, don't write such code.

Answer (score 0):

Since your char is SIGNED it can be between -128 and 127 (in 8 bits) and in that for you are incrementing until it gets to max value and then overflows and becomes the - value since that's how negative value is written in bits.
Take a look at the following pic:

[image]

p.s. with some printing inside the loop you could figure it out yourself too.

Comment: That picture looks nice at first, but it's actually hugely misleading in that it presents the very different "excess 128" representation, *not* two's complement.

Comment: I wasn't looking into it just trying to give graphical representation which had 8 bit number representation. I guess that the new image has better explanation but on a smaller sample. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks for fixing.  Pictures like that are great -- as long as they're accurate!

Answer (score 0):

Actually at each iteration, loop will increment `i` by `1`, which lead us to `i = 127`.

- Now, lets look its binary representation `0111-1111`.
- Now if we increment it by `1`.Then
- `0111-1111` + `0000-0001` = `1000-0000`
- Now, analyse this, MSB is set, which means it is a negative number
- Negative numbers are save as 2's complement
- 2's complement of `1000-0000` = `-127`
- Hence loop breaks

Hope you will get it.

Comment: Although this is most probably what's happening, it needs all the *not guaranteed assumptions* I've listed in my answer. I don't think it's a good idea to write an answer that makes it look like this was actually *defined* behavior.